# Why is this code blocking another requests since I am using only async functions?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, mongoose

I can't figure out why this code is blocking/preventing the server to fulfill concurrent requests, since I am only using async code. Can someone throw some light?

I am using mongoose streaming feature! The following is an express route.

```
function getChart(req, res, next) {
    var stream = Model.find({}).stream({
        transform: JSON.stringify
    });

    stream.on('data', function(record) {
        res.write(record);    
    });

    stream.on('end', function() {
        res.end();
    });
}
```

The problem can be verified when requesting around 10000 records from database, which takes around 10 seconds. During this time I open another tab and make a request to any other route, say `/home`, the content of `/home` only arrives immediately after the first request finishes!

**EDIT**

I have just made some basic tests (even set mongoose connection pool to a higher value) and now I know that the problem is not with mongoose, but with nodejs itself or perhaps with express. I created the following test app:

```
var express = require('express'),
    http = require('http'),
    app = express();

app.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
    console.log('> Request received!');

    setTimeout(function() {
        console.log('> Request sent!');
        res.send(200);
    }, 5000);
});

app.listen(8000, function() {
    console.log(' > APP LISTENING');
    console.log(' > maxSockets: ' + http.globalAgent.maxSockets);
});
```

Within the 5 seconds of the first request I open more 3 tabs on chrome and make more requests, message `> Request received!` is only shown after first ones are already sent.

I get `5` as the number of `maxSockets`

Can anyone help me?

Comment: What version of node.js and mongoose are you running? Any chance that piping the stream to res may solve the problem, as [in the docs?](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#query_Query-stream) Something such as `Model.find({}).stream({ transform: JSON.stringify }).pipe(res);`

Comment: @pk-nb I am using node `v0.10.25` and mongoose `v3.8.3` - Piping is not an option because I actually do some little processing before writing data to `res` stream.